# Read a hashtagged "##" textual data as a data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a textual dataset (`m`) that is shown below. I was wondering given its hash-tagged format, is there is way to read it correctly in `R` as a data.frame?

```
m <-
"
##    Item1 Item2 Item3 Item4 Item5 Item6 Item7 Item8 Item9 Item10 Item11
## 1      0     4     5     1     2     8     9     7     6      4      3
## 2      4     0     9     7     1     5     6     7     8      5      4
## 3      5     9     0     6     3     1     2     4     5      7      9
## 4      1     7     6     0     5     4     3     2     7      8      9
## 5      2     1     3     5     0     4     6     7     8      1      2
## 6      8     5     1     4     4     0     1     2     4      3      2
## 7      9     6     2     3     6     1     0     6     7      5      2
## 8      7     7     4     2     7     2     6     0     4      5      3
## 9      6     8     5     7     8     4     7     4     0      6      7
## 10     4     5     7     8     1     3     5     5     6      0      5
## 11     3     4     9     9     2     2     2     3     7      5      0
## 12     2     2     4     2     3     3     3     2     8      6      5
## 13     1     3     6     7     4     1     1     6     9      4      6
## 14     4     4     8     9     9     3     2     5     1      2      7
## 15     3     5     9     9     7     2     3     3     2      5      4
##    Item12 Item13 Item14 Item15
## 1       2      1      4      3
## 2       2      3      4      5
## 3       4      6      8      9
## 4       2      7      9      9
## 5       3      4      9      7
## 6       3      1      3      2
## 7       3      1      2      3
## 8       2      6      5      3
## 9       8      9      1      2
## 10      6      4      2      5
## 11      5      6      7      4
## 12      0      7      8      8
## 13      7      0      9      4
## 14      8      9      0      6
## 15      8      4      6      0
"
```

Comment: Does Item12 start below Item1?

Comment: @zx8754, no it comes as a column after `item11`. The dataset is from [this website](https://www.rpubs.com/mhanauer/387153).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest it to remove those annoying `##`  and then read the two parts of the table separately.

Bind them together at the end to get your expected result.

```
m <- gsub("## ", "", m)
m1 <- read.table(text = m, nrows = 15)
m2 <- read.table(text = m, skip = 17)
cbind(m1, m2)
```

```
   Item1 Item2 Item3 Item4 Item5 Item6 Item7 Item8 Item9 Item10 Item11 Item12 Item13 Item14 Item15
1      0     4     5     1     2     8     9     7     6      4      3      2      1      4      3
2      4     0     9     7     1     5     6     7     8      5      4      2      3      4      5
3      5     9     0     6     3     1     2     4     5      7      9      4      6      8      9
4      1     7     6     0     5     4     3     2     7      8      9      2      7      9      9
5      2     1     3     5     0     4     6     7     8      1      2      3      4      9      7
6      8     5     1     4     4     0     1     2     4      3      2      3      1      3      2
7      9     6     2     3     6     1     0     6     7      5      2      3      1      2      3
8      7     7     4     2     7     2     6     0     4      5      3      2      6      5      3
9      6     8     5     7     8     4     7     4     0      6      7      8      9      1      2
10     4     5     7     8     1     3     5     5     6      0      5      6      4      2      5
11     3     4     9     9     2     2     2     3     7      5      0      5      6      7      4
12     2     2     4     2     3     3     3     2     8      6      5      0      7      8      8
13     1     3     6     7     4     1     1     6     9      4      6      7      0      9      4
14     4     4     8     9     9     3     2     5     1      2      7      8      9      0      6
15     3     5     9     9     7     2     3     3     2      5      4      8      4      6      0
```

Answer (score 0):

if all rows start with "##" and if you know that true rows have a row number in the beginning and if all header start with "Item" (lots of ifs :D) you could do something awful like this (which would give you some flexibility on the data structure)

```
# split according to seperator and linebreak
strsplit(m,split="\n|##") %>%
  .[[1]] %>%
  .[.!=""] %>%
  # split according to row names
  strsplit(split="^ [0-9]{1,2}") %>%
  unlist() %>%
  .[.!=""] %>%
  dplyr::as_tibble() %>%
  # flag header
  dplyr::mutate(HEADER=grepl("Item",value)) %>%
  # split into groups (each group will be used with bind_cols)
  dplyr::mutate(GRP=cumsum(HEADER)) %>%
  dplyr::group_by(GRP) %>%
  dplyr::group_split() %>%
  dplyr::bind_cols() %>%
  # reduce to relevant columns
  dplyr::select(dplyr::matches("value")) %>%
  magrittr::set_colnames(paste0("X",seq_len(ncol(.)))) %>%
  tidyr::unite("X",dplyr::everything(),sep=" ") %>%
  # create comma seperated list
  .$X %>%
  gsub("^ +| +$","",.) %>%
  gsub(" +",",",.)
```

Comment: That's pretty unreadable.. also it doesn't work. I get this error: `Error in ncol(dmmy) : object "dmmy" not found`

Comment: It's not that readable, that's true. But also the initial situation was a mess. Anyways. I fixed the problem and now the code works